# Using Ajax Get/Post methods with Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, post, get

I am pretty new with Client side code and completely clueless when it comes to server-side (Django, in particular). What I am attempting to do is click a button which sends a get request to the server, and then posts it on the page (using [jGlideMenu](http://www.jqueryplugins.com/plugin/27/)).

I know the code should look something like the following:

```
        $('#clickID').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:"someURLGoesHere",
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(data){
                    $('#someEl_2').html(data)
                },
                dataType: JSON
            });
        });
```

I have no idea what to use for the URL. Do I need to refer to the url.py file? views.py? models.py? Maybe a particular var inside one of those files? Also do I need to use relative directories?

All the tutorials I found use PHP instead so I am not sure if it is the same. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put in whatever URL you have setup to go to the appropriate function to process the data in the views.py file. If you have this in your urls.py:

`url(r'^/testing$','proj.app.testing')` you would put in `'/testing'` for your ajax request.

Comment: Austin, even if the views.py is in a different directory? For instance, the .py file is in main/views.py and the .js is in main/js/index.js?

Comment: won't matter where the JS file is located. All the matters is that you're calling the correct URL. JS path is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert the content from your Django app, you can use jQuery's [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method:

```
$('#result').load('path/to/script.py');
```

You will need to hit a Python script which is publicly accessible. Whereas with other MVC frameworks, you'd hit the controller, because [Django has a slightly different methodology](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter05.html#the-mtv-or-mvc-development-pattern), you will need to hit a view, since these control access to your models and handle most of the business logic:

> In Django’s interpretation of MVC, the “view” describes the data that
>   gets presented to the user; it’s not necessarily just how the data
>   looks, but which data is presented. In contrast, Ruby on Rails and
>   similar frameworks suggest that the controller’s job includes deciding
>   which data gets presented to the user, whereas the view is strictly
>   how the data looks, not which data is presented.